# How to save a django variable in Template after refreshing?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django template that contains a button. If clicked, it will display the current time. My intention is to view this time even after a user refreshes the page. However, the data gets deleted after refreshing. How can I do this? Currently, the time is calculated using an external script in my Django root project. After execution, I used a HttpResponse in my views module and place this data in my HTML file using an AJAX call.

This is my current code so far:

**time.py (external script):**

```
from datetime import datetime

def time():
    current_time = datetime.now()
    datetime = current_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return datetime
```

**views.py:**

```
from time import time   #importing external script

#calling the time() method that calculates current time
def time(request):
    current_time = time()
    return HttpResponse(current_time)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from users import views as users_views      #app that stores views.py module
urlpatterns = [
    path('current_time/', users_views.time, name = 'current_time'),
]
```

**home.js:**

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/current_time/",
        success: function(data) { 
            $('#button').html(data)     //display time after user clicks on button
        }
    });
});
```

**home.html:**

```
..... #all HTML layout stuff
<div>
    <p> Last seen: 
        <button type="button" id='button'> {{current_time}} </button> #time accessed from views.py
    </p> 
</div>
```

How to save the time variable after refreshing the page?

Comment: Make a simple model in models.py and save the value in database. Save a value in it if user clicks on button and always return value from the database.

Comment: JavaScript is totally capable to do that without Python and without a request. And BTW naming a module `time` will disallow you to import the built-in module with the same name. Many libraries rely on it.

Comment: @KlausD. naming it time was just an example. I will change it for sure! How can you do it in JS? Do you have any sources online?

Comment: @ShwetaChandel can you please show me a demonstration? I have tried your advice but I'm getting a lot of errors. It would be really great if you could show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another script that would run on page load:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
      cache: false,
        url: "/current_time/",
        success: function(data) { 
            $('#button').html(data)
        }});
});
```

Comment: By the way, what does cache: false mean in Ajax? I found this online but didn't know what it means.

Comment: @danny_boy When you set `cache` to `false`, jQuery will append a timestamp to the URL, so the browser won’t cache it. Also, if you just need the current time, you don't need to send a request to server - you can do it with javascript itself.